# Analyse SQL Server histogram table

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to access the histograms values in SQL Server from an SQL command? It is easy to see a histogram of an attribute using DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS, however, is it possible to access the histogram table in an SQL SELECT command or in some T-SQL procedure/function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember this trick from a Video of Kimberley Tripp,so a quick search yielded below

```
 create table histogram (
        [RANGE_HI_KEY] sql_variant
    ,   [RANGE_ROWS] sql_variant
    ,   [EQ_ROWS] sql_variant
    ,   [DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS]  sql_variant
    ,   [AVG_RANGE_ROWS] sql_variant
    )

insert into histogram
exec ('dbcc show_statistics(''dbo.orders'',''_WA_Sys_00000001_29572725'') with  HISTOGRAM')
```

Now you can access the table ..You can do the same for Stat_header and density_vector

References:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/00a3fc6f-bc42-46da-9574-088522976fbb/dbcc-showstatistics-how-to-send-result-to-table?forum=sqltools